# Different vibrate pattern for 2 notifications in same channel

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have many notifications in my application and have categorised them into channels regading to their app functionality. 
Now lets take this example. There are 3 notification N1, N2, N3. All are in same catogory and same channel C1.

Now what I want to achieve is that give N1 and N2 this vibration pattern : `channel.setVibrationPattern(longArrayOf(1000,1000,1000,1000));`

and N3 this vibration pattern : `channel.setVibrationPattern(longArrayOf(0));`

but the channel I have used is :

```
val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel("test", "test", importance).apply {
                description = "test"
            }
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
```

So now the issue is that even N3 gets vibration. Why is that so?

Comment: update your `NotificationCompat.Builder` with vibration pattern you want and notify your `NotificationManager`

Comment: Already doing it but it is not working.

Comment: Do not set vibration to a single `channel` set vibration patters to `NotificationCompat.Builder`. A single notification channel can have one vibration patter I guess, also there is a bug, you have to reinstall the app to get the changes in vibration pattern changes in notification channel

Comment: Yes, i always re-install when i make a change in channel. But as the question states, in one channel i need to send 2 notifications, one has vibration pattern, other has 0 vibration pattern.

Comment: As the comment states - change vibration patter in `Builder`

Comment: But it does not work.